# ¿Cómo muestro el estado?

Tags: python

Estoy con problemas para poder devolver el estado, el resto funciona perfecto. ¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna idea de por qué no lo muestra?

```
class Alumno(): 
    nombre = ""
    apellido = ""
    notas = []
    promedio = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre=input("ingrese el nombre del alumno: ")
        self.apellido=input("ingrese el apellido del alumno: ")
        self.estado=""
        self.nota=0
       
        while True:
            nota=int(input("Ingrese una nota entre 1 y 10, o 0 para terminar"))
            if nota!=0:
                self.notas.append(nota)
            else:
                self.promedio=sum(self.notas)/len(self.notas)
                break
    
        
             
               
    def __str__(self):
        
         if self.nota>=7:
            Estado="promociona"
            if self.nota <=7 and self.nota>=4:
                Estado="Final"
                if self.nota <4:
                    Estado="Recursa"
         mensaje= self.apellido+', '+self.nombre+', '+str(self.promedio)+self.estado
         return mensaje
        
        
        
alumno = Alumno()   
print(alumno)

class Alumno(): 
    nombre = ""
    apellido = ""
    notas = []
    promedio = 0
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre=input("ingrese el nombre del alumno: ")
        self.apellido=input("ingrese el apellido del alumno: ")
        self.estado=""
        self.nota=0
       
        while True:
            nota=int(input("Ingrese una nota entre 1 y 10, o 0 para terminar"))
            if nota!=0:
                self.notas.append(nota)
            else:
                self.promedio=sum(self.notas)/len(self.notas)
                break
    
        
             
               
    def __str__(self):
        
         if self.nota>=7:
            Estado="promociona"
            if self.nota <=7 and self.nota>=4:
                Estado="Final"
                if self.nota <4:
                    Estado="Recursa"
         mensaje= self.apellido+', '+self.nombre+', '+str(self.promedio)+self.estado 
         return mensaje
        
        
        
alumno = Alumno()   
print(alumno)
```

Solo me deja ver la nota, el nombre y el apellido, y necesito poder ver el estado. Probé distintos ingresos pero ninguno me funcionó. Es lo único que me falta; el resto del programa se ejecuta perfecto, pero al estado no lo muestra.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. "probé distintos ingresos pero ninguno me funcionó": entonces pon lo que has intentado hasta el momento, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Recuerda que la pregunta y sus posteriores respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar. Además, pulsa en [edit] y explica el enunciado: _¿qué es estado?_

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta es que `__str__` está todo mal. Repasemos:

```
def __str__(self):
    
     if self.nota>=7:
        Estado="promociona"
        if self.nota <=7 and self.nota>=4:
            Estado="Final"
            if self.nota <4:
                Estado="Recursa"
     mensaje= self.apellido+', '+self.nombre+', '+str(self.promedio)+self.estado 
     return mensaje
```

1. El atributo `self.nota` no está calculado en ninguna parte.
2. El atributo `self.estado` no está calculado en ninguna parte.
3. Los `if` están mal escritos, deben ser `if-elif-else`.
4. Calculas `Estado` y luego no lo usas para nada.

La versión correcta es:

```
def __str__(self):

    if self.nota >= 7:
        estado = "promociona"
    elif self.nota >= 4:
        estado = "Final"
    else:
        estado = "Recursa"

    mensaje = self.apellido + ', ' + self.nombre + ', ' + str(self.promedio) + estado
    return mensaje
```

También hay problemas con el resto del código; cosas que faltan, sobran o están mal puestas.

Comment: genial gracias por contestar !

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que si estás calculando un "Estado", tendrás que mostrarlo en los datos y además el if lo tenias mal.

```
def __str__(self):
    
     if self.nota>=7:
        Estado="promociona"
     elif self.nota <=7 and self.nota>=4:
        Estado="Final"
     else: # self.nota <4
        Estado="Recursa"
     mensaje= self.apellido+', '+self.nombre+', '+str(self.promedio)+Estado
     return mensaje
```

Por otra parte, te aconsejo que uses f-strings para componer el mensaje:

```
 mensaje= f"{self.apellido}, {self.nombre}, {str(self.promedio)} {Estado}"
```

La legibilidad mejora bastante.

Comment: El `if` está mal. Sólo funciona cuando self.nota >= 7.

Comment: cierto!!!! no lo había visto. lo corrijo.

Comment: Recordemos que los f-strings fueron agregados en Python 3.6, por lo que no funcionarian si el op usa una version mas baja.